# Neo4J Poor Object Creation Performance

Tags: java, neo4j

I am fairly new to Neo4j, but I managed to get it working fairly well...or so it seemed. I created an embedded database and it worked fine when the graph was incredibly small (a few hundred nodes), however, when it hit around a thousand nodes, it started having lag issues with db object creation (aka nodes or edges). It went from around 10 ms for creation of single objects at smaller db sizes to about 100 ms for creation of single objects with a thousand nodes in the db.

This kind of lag won't work for my project and, honestly, at that size it shouldn't be happening I wouldn't think. I have done my research and can't seem to find too much that helped. I have found mentions of speed differences between Cypher and the Java core API, but have tried both and can't seem to get the speed any better. I was also thinking maybe there was too much transaction overhead, but I don't think that's the case since it doesn't seem to be a problem with the smaller database sizes.

Like I mentioned though, I am new to this so I'm assuming that there is just something I'm missing.

Here is a piece of my current code for uploading for reference:

```
    try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
        // Perform DB operations

        Node node = graphDb.createNode(NodeTypes.WORD);

        Label label = DynamicLabel.label("word");
        node.addLabel(label);

        node.setProperty("word", graphWordNode.getWord());

        tx.success();
    }
```

If I missed any significant details let me know.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you set up indexes for the node properties you are interested in?

Comment: I have not. I will test that and get back to you.

Comment: Such a simple little thing, but that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up the appropriate indexes for the properties you are interested in will greatly speed up neo4j, as it will any database.